# Example of meteor compiling custom bootstrap less?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less, meteor

I'd like to use meteor with some custom bootstrap less.

Can anyone share an example of a meteor project that is setup to compile custom bootstrap .less files?

Or do I need to use external .less preprocessor (In other projects I use LiverReload for this) in concert with meteor?

Would be nice if the bootstrap less compilation was under one meteor flavoured roof.

Any insight much appreciated!
-j

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far it is not possible to directly include the vanilla bootstrap less source files in a meteor project because the less package only compiles less files in parallel and thus breaks cross-file @variables references.

Answer (score 7):

you can add less support via

```
meteor add less
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: ...and for bootstrap, you need to change all but `bootstrap.less` files' extension to `lessimport`. Thanks for the tip btw. :)

Comment: or mrt add less with meteorite

Comment: @kgpdeveloper you should update your meteor instance to the >= 0.9.0 version where they introduced the build in package system.  https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/08/26/meteor-090-new-packaging-system

Answer (score 1):

I can't vouch for it myself but it looks like this is what you are asking for: https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/bootstrap3-less (see the github link if you don't use meteorite but you probably should).

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LESS, you can use node.js's (imo superior) Stylus CSS preprocessor.

Instead of LESS bootstrap use bootstrap-stylus.

Then add in [stylus-mixin](https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/stylus-mixin) which was created to solve this problem and allows you to enjoy the full capabilities of stylus, mixins, and variables.